# SQL Query - Add values from one row to all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have an SQL Server Query where I get data from multiple tables, I am currently stuck with this scenario:

I get the data per customer and product. For example I have 5 products: A, B, C, D, E  then there is one extra row where PRODUCT IS NULL but the rest of the columns contains values that should be for each of my product.

I get the data like this:

```
TID  Customer   PRODUCT     VAL1        VAL2        VAL3        VAL4
1    CUST       NULL        CONTENT1    CONTENT2    CONTENT3    CONTENT4  
1    CUST       A           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    
1    CUST       B           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    
1    CUST       C           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    
1    CUST       D           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    
1    CUST       E           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

how can I transform it into this output?

```
TID  Customer   PRODUCT     VAL1        VAL2        VAL3        VAL4
1    CUST       A           CONTENT1    CONTENT2    CONTENT3    CONTENT4  
1    CUST       B           CONTENT1    CONTENT2    CONTENT3    CONTENT4  
1    CUST       C           CONTENT1    CONTENT2    CONTENT3    CONTENT4  
1    CUST       D           CONTENT1    CONTENT2    CONTENT3    CONTENT4  
1    CUST       E           CONTENT1    CONTENT2    CONTENT3    CONTENT4  


EDIT:
```

in the result I have multiple records, by TID, CUSTOMER, PRODUCT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.tid, t.customer, t.product
             max(t.val1) over (partition by t.tid) as val1,
             max(t.val2) over (partition by t.tid) as val2,
             max(t.val3) over (partition by t.tid) as val3,
             max(t.val4) over (partition by t.tid) as val4
      from t
     ) t
where t.product is not null;
```

Another method uses `join`:

```
select tp.id, tp.customer, tp.product,
       tv.val1, tv.val2, tv.val3, tv.val4
from t tp join
     t tv
     on tp.id = tv.id and
        tp.product is not null and
        tv.product is null;
```

Comment: Thanks mate this works great. one thing I forgot to mention is that I have multiple records per customer and products. For the initial scenario it works fine.

Comment: Never mind! Solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_value()` window analytic function and then filter by `not null` values of `PRODUCT` column :

```
with tab2 as
(    
select TID,Customer,PRODUCT,
       first_value(VAL1) over ( order by PRODUCT ) as VAL1,
       first_value(VAL2) over ( order by PRODUCT ) as VAL2,
       first_value(VAL3) over ( order by PRODUCT ) as VAL3,
       first_value(VAL4) over ( order by PRODUCT ) as VAL4       
  from tab                    
)
select * from tab2 where PRODUCT is not null
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=5c7f7a154c9d63f77c13e746ceeab88e)</kbd>

P.S.using is enough depeding on the sample data,

`first_value(..) over (partition by Customer order by PRODUCT )` or

`first_value(..) over (partition by TID order by PRODUCT )` might be considered for enlarged data set.